# Como puedo usar la funcion case when then else end en report studio 10.2.2 cognos

Tags: sql

Hola  estoy tratando de hacer esto pero no me funciona quien puede explicarme como?

```
case [CD PRODUCTO] when [CD PRODUCTO]='100476' 
                    and [CD PRODUCTO]='100222' then [MONTO VENTA] = 0
else [CD PRODUCTO] end
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Debería colocar el error que le muestra... Intente hacerlo asi: `case when ( .... and .....) then (...) else (...) end` haciendo uso de los paréntesis `()`.  Esto estaría mal `case [CD PRODUCTO]` y Que tipo de dato es `[CD PRODUCTO]` ?

Comment: El tipo de dato de cd_producto es string.    esta es otra forma de como lo estoy tratando de hacer.....                                                     IF ([CD PRODUCTO] ='100476' AND [CD PRODUCTO]='100222')
THEN ([MONTO VENTA])= (0)  ELSE ([CD PRODUCTO])

Comment: Y cual es el error que le presenta?

Comment: El error que presenta es que se ha producido un error de analisis cerca de la posicion 78 (QE-DEF-0260)

Comment: Esos errores en cognos no me deja copiarlos.

Comment: Haz una captura de pantalla y coloca la imagen del error.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Error al usar expresion case e if report studio 10.2.2]
he intentado hacerlo de varias formas, es algo bien sencillo pero con esta herramienta lo hace dificil de aplicar.

Comment: Coloca esta información tu pregunta original [da click aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/166824/edit) y coloca esta información ahí y luego elimina esto. Además deberías realizar el [tour] para entender mejor como funciona el sitio.